# Maximum Size of patch to customSchemas?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm having an issue with the SDK.  I followed [this guide](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxT8XK9DVM0MGP/How-to-Set-Up-Federated-Single-Sign-On-to-AWS-Using-Google-Apps) to get SSO with AWS.  I'm able to add 4 roles using my code, but after that I get a 413.

My schema contains all of the roles under the SSO role array.  So, each patch I make requires me to resubmit the entire role array according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/performance#patch):

> Note about arrays: Patch requests that contain arrays replace the existing array with the one you provide. You cannot modify, add, or delete items in an array in a piecemeal fashion.

---

**Python Snippet:**

```python
service.users().patch(userKey=email, body=new_custom_schema).execute()
```

new_custom_schema is a dictionary containing all nodes including and below customSchema.

---

**Error**

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 413 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/user@domain.com?alt=json returned "Profile quota is exceeded.: Data is too large for">
```

---

**Sample Schema Insert:**

```json
{
  "fields":
  [
    {
      "fieldName": "role",
      "fieldType": "STRING",
      "readAccessType": "ADMINS_AND_SELF",    
      "multiValued": true
    }
  ],
  "schemaName": "SSO"
}
```

---

**Sample User Patch:**

```json
{
  "customSchemas": {
    "SSO": {
      "role": [
        {
          "customType": "AWSaccount1ReadOnly", 
          "type": "work", 
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/gapps_readonly,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/GoogleApps"
        }, 
        {
          "customType": "AWSaccount1Admin", 
          "type": "work", 
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/gapps_admin,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:saml-provider/GoogleApps"
        }, 
        {
          "customType": "AWSaccount2ReadOnly", 
          "type": "work", 
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::5101520253035:role/gapps_readonly,arn:aws:iam::5101520253035:saml-provider/GoogleApps"
        }, 
        {
          "customType": "AWSaccount2Admin", 
          "type": "work", 
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::5101520253035:role/gapps_admin,arn:aws:iam::5101520253035:saml-provider/GoogleApps"
        }, 
        {
          "customType": "AWSaccount3ReadOnly", 
          "type": "work", 
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::3691215182124:role/gapps_readonly,arn:aws:iam::3691215182124:saml-provider/GoogleApps"
        }, 
        {
          "customType": "AWSaccount3Admin", 
          "type": "work", 
          "value": "arn:aws:iam::3691215182124:role/gapps_admin,arn:aws:iam::3691215182124:saml-provider/GoogleApps"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*In this example, I'm able to submit the first 5 without issue*

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show sample new_custom_schema bodys that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi @JayLee, I've updated with a tested schema and user patch.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a support ticket to Google and found out that there is a 4KB (~1000 characters) limit on the multivalued field in a custom schema.

So, there are a couple options:

1. Choose a different SAML IdP
2. <strike>Create multiple SAML Apps as needed to work around the limit.</strike>

**[Update]**

You can't have multiple SAML apps with the same entity ID.

**[Update 2]**

The new limit seems to be roughly double the old limit.  Somewhere between  2087 - 2315 characters

**[Update 3]**

It looks like this limit has been significantly increased.  I have not run out of space yet.

Comment: Do you pass "body" as a dict or string? neither is working for me

Comment: It's a dict with the following format:

`schemas["customSchemas"][AWS_SSO_NAME]["role"] = []`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an answer on the size of the request:

```
array_length * 100 + SUM(value_lengths) <= ~32000
```

Example:

```
[ "{500 bytes}", "{500 bytes}", "{500 bytes}" ]
array_length is 3
SUM(value_lengths) is 1500
3 * 100 + 1500 + 4 = 1804
```