# Error Code 413 encountered in Admin SDK Directory API (Users: patch)

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am a G Suite Super Admin. I have set up Google Single Sign On (SSO) for our AWS accounts inside our G Suite. As we have several AWS accounts, we need to run the "Users: patch" (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/patch#try-it) to include other AWS accounts for Google Single Sign On.

While provisioning additional AWS accounts to Google Single Sign on, we encountered error "Code: 413" after running the above mentioned patch. Details below:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "uploadTooLarge",
    "message": "Profile quota is exceeded.: Data is too large for "
   }
  ],
  "code": 413,
  "message": "Profile quota is exceeded.: Data is too large for "
 }
}
```

What could be the possible cause of this error? Are there any workaround for this? Else, are there other ways to provision multiple AWS accounts using Google Single Sign On?

Thank you in advance for your patience and assistance in this.

Answer (score 0):

Notice what the error is saying. You're probably going way beyond the designated limit. Try using the solution from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024817/maximum-size-of-patch-to-customschemas) which is to:

> choose a different SAML ldP. New limit was said to be somewhere
>   between 2087 - 2315 characters